# Proving nonexistence of initial values for which ODE remains within some bounds

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider a second order ODE

$\ddot{x} = f(t,x,\dot{x})$

for which there does not exist any explicit solutions for $x$ or $\dot{x}$.

Are there any techniques for showing that there does not exist any initial values $x_0$ and $\dot{x}_0$ for which $|x|<k$ as $t\rightarrow \infty$ for some $k\in \mathbb{R}$, without having to find explicit solutions for $x$?